# Azure Map's Autosuggest in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-maps

I have been trying to add Azure Map's Autosuggest to my Angular project but it is not working. Can anyone provide the codes for Azure Map's Autosuggest in Angular?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Azure Maps doesn't have a UI for autosuggest, just a service. So, the easiest way for you to create an autosuggest UI is to use an existing autosuggest component that lets you connect to a REST service. For example: https://github.com/mauriciogentile/angular-livesearch